# django makemigrations raise error after remove a function in models.py

Tags: python, django, model, filefield, makemigrations

I define a model named **Foo** which has a **FileField** named **bar**, and I define a function **baz** which is callable used for bar's **upload_to** arguement in same file. When I removed the **bar** field and **baz** funcion and perform **makemigrations** operations, it raise error "AttributeError: module 'models' has no attribute 'baz'".

How can I solve the bug?

*below is snippet demo*

```
import os
import time

from django.db import models


def baz(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    fn = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    com = fn + '.' + ext
    return os.path.join('', com)


class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bar = models.FileField(upload_to=baz)  # wants to remove
```

Comment: Django raises this error because it cannot reconcile the missing function with the migration history. You should find the previous migration files where it is named, and delete the function name where it says upload_to.  Then try your migration again.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

It's because of `migration file`. To resolve you can change upload path to string in `migrations` file that contains `bar` field initial create. **Change migrations field `upload_to` path.**

Comment: thanks!  when I set `bar` argument `baz` into `None` in **migration file** and `makemigrations`, it works!  but I have to modify **migration file** manually locally and on remote server when deploy.